# deployment of activemq-web-console-5.9.1.war to Jetty 9.1.4 fails

Tags: java, jetty, activemq-classic, jetty-9

When I deploy activemq-web-console-5.9.1.war to Jetty server version 9.1.4 it fails with the following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No such servlet: __org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.JspPropertyGroupServlet__
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.updateMappings(ServletHandler.java:1449)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.setServletMappings(ServletHandler.java:1563)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.servlet.ServletHandler.addServletMapping(ServletHandler.java:999)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.StandardDescriptorProcessor.visitJspConfig(StandardDescriptorProcessor.java:1414)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.visit(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:85)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.IterativeDescriptorProcessor.process(IterativeDescriptorProcessor.java:72)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.MetaData.resolve(MetaData.java:394)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.startContext(WebAppContext.java:1350)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandler.doStart(ContextHandler.java:744)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext.doStart(WebAppContext.java:497)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.AbstractLifeCycle.start(AbstractLifeCycle.java:68)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.start(ContainerLifeCycle.java:125)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:289)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.addBean(ContainerLifeCycle.java:221)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.component.ContainerLifeCycle.updateBeans(ContainerLifeCycle.java:771)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.setHandlers(HandlerCollection.java:89)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.ContextHandlerCollection.setHandlers(ContextHandlerCollection.java:144)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.server.handler.HandlerCollection.addHandler(HandlerCollection.java:155)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.bindings.StandardDeployer.processBinding(StandardDeployer.java:41)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.AppLifeCycle.runBindings(AppLifeCycle.java:186)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.requestAppGoal(DeploymentManager.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.DeploymentManager.addApp(DeploymentManager.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:180)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.deploy.providers.ScanningAppProvider$1.fileAdded(ScanningAppProvider.java:64)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportAddition(Scanner.java:605)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.reportDifferences(Scanner.java:528)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner.scan(Scanner.java:391)
    at org.eclipse.jetty.util.Scanner$1.run(Scanner.java:329)
    at java.util.TimerThread.mainLoop(Timer.java:555)
    at java.util.TimerThread.run(Timer.java:505)
```

Deployment to Jetty version 8.1.12 works fine.

Comment: Jetty 9 is not supported in that AMQ version.

Comment: It works whith ActiveMQ version 5.10.0